# How do I handle null values from ColdFusion queries?

Tags: coldfusion, null, cfquery

If one of the columns in the returned coldfusion query result set has a NULL, how do we check if the value of this column being NULL?

Should we just say `<cfif queryname.columnname[i] EQ ''>`  OR `<cfif queryname.columnname[i] eq 'NULL'>` ?

Answer (score 12):

Null value will only be returned as empty string in a query object.

Answer (score 9):

Ideally, you would use your database's `ifnull` (or similar) method to convert null values to something appropriate before they reach CF.

If not, they come back as an empty string, so your first `cfif` is correct.

Comment: Agreed.  If you need to distinguish a true NULL value from an empty string, you need to do that in the query.

Comment: And sometimes I wish it didn't work like this. NULL can actually <i>mean</i> something in certain circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an oracle database you could use the NVL method and modify your query to wrap the column.

```
<cfset var nullstringvalue = "THELASTNAMEFIELDISNULL" />
<cfquery name="lastnamelookup" ....>
  SELECT NVL(lastname, 'LASTNAMEISNULL') AS lastname
</cfquery>
<cfif lastnamelookup.lastname EQ nullstringvalue>
     ...do null case work...
</cfif>
```

The trick would be in determining the correct bogus string to use in this case, then testing for it.